# how can push select options into array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

how can i push `select` `options` into `array` of `objects` so that it constitutes a single `select box`.

i tried this

```
  <select name="fruit">
    <option selected="true" value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="kela">kela</option>
 </select>


var fruits = [];
$('#fruits').find('select').each(function(){
   fruits.push({
     selectName: $(this).attr('name'),
     optionValue: $(this).attr('value')

   });
});

console.log(fruits);
```

**my question:**  how to push all `options` values so that i can get a one `select box`?  i mean the `array object` must belong to a single `select` box

```js
var fruits = [];
$('#fruits').find('select').each(function(){
   fruits.push({
     selectName: $(this).attr('name'),
     optionValue: [] // i want all the options values to be contained either in array or any other way
   
   });
});

console.log(fruits);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fruits">
 <select name="fruit"><option selected="true" value="apple">apple</option><option value="banana">banana</option><option value="kela">kela</option></select>
 </div>
```

Comment: In short you just want the selected object in an array ?

Comment: There is no `value` attribute in `select`

Comment: @FlyingGambit, whole `select box options` itself to be `pushed` into array

Comment: @Leopard, i want `push` all the `options` into `array object` thats all

Comment: after `find()` and before `.each()`, add `.children()`

Comment: And save the select name in a var, since $(this) won't refer to the select anymore once you add .children() to get the options.

Comment: @IvanKaraman, leave about the  `"optionValue": undefined` in that place i want all the 3 `options value`

Comment: @user5405873 check my answer below

Comment: @user5405873 my answer updated for two selects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know two ways, how to do this

```
var fruits = [];
$('#fruits').find('select').children().each(function(){
   fruits.push({
     selectName: $(this).parent().attr('name'),
     optionValue: $(this).attr('value') // all the options value

   });
});
console.log(fruits);
```

**OR**

```js
/*var fruits = [];
$('#fruits').find('select').children().each(function(){
   fruits.push({
     selectName: $(this).parent().attr('name'),
     optionValue: $(this).attr('value') // all the options value

   });
});
console.log(fruits);*/

var select = {};
$('#fruits').find('select').each(function(){
  var propName = $(this).attr('name');
  select[propName] = [];
  $(this).children().each(function(){
    select[propName].push({
     selectName: $(this).text(),
     optionValue: $(this).attr('value') // all the options value
     });
   });
});

console.log(select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fruits">
 <select name="fruit"><option selected="true" value="apple">apple</option><option value="banana">banana</option><option value="kela">kela</option></select>
  <select name="vegetable"><option selected="true" value="potato">potato</option><option value="tomato">tomato</option><option value="cabbage">cabbage</option></select>
 </div>
```

Comment: yeh you have understood my question !!

Comment: what if there are ` 2 select box`  then this would become difficult for me to identify which `optionValue` belongs to which `select box`? do you have any other solution?

Comment: @user5405873 create jsfiddle with layout please

Comment: @user5405873 `selectName` its name from `<select>` tag ?
or name from option ?
we can add one more property with select tag name...

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that `<select>` elements can also contain an `<optgroup>` children elements. I've created a little fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/8xboz1gn/

I've created a method to which you can pass an jQuery element. It looks to all `<option>` items within and build an array with key, value pairs (or id, text in my case :P):

```
function getOptions($elem)
{
    var items = [];
    var $options =  $elem.find('option');

    $options.each(function() {
        var $option = $(this);
        items.push({
            'id': $option.val(),
            'text': $option.text()
        });
    });
    return items;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fruits = [];
$('#fruits').find('select').children().each(function(){
   fruits.push({
     optionValue: $(this).attr('value')
   
   });
});

console.log(fruits);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fruits">
 <select name="fruit"><option selected="true" value="apple">apple</option><option value="banana">banana</option><option value="kela">kela</option></select>
 </div>
```